# open a new line separated text file in python

Tags: python, string, csv

Using the python `open` built-in function in this way:

```
with open('myfile.csv', mode='r') as rows:
    for r in rows:
        print(r.__repr__())
```

I obtain this ouput

```
'col1,col2,col3\n'
'fst,snd,trd\n'
'1,2,3\n'
```

I don't want the `\n` character. Do you know some efficient way to remove that char (in place of the obvious `r.replace('\n','')`)?

Comment: `open` has a parameter called __newline__ in which you decide how you want the `/n` character to be translated. Setting it to `''` will return the newline character untranslated. For more information check [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open).

Comment: @VasilisG. That will leave the newline character in the string as `\r\n`

Comment: There's nothing here to indicate that the lines are CRLF terminated. I think @enneppi just wants to remove the LF.

Comment: @enneppi, unless you're manually reading and parsing a CSV file as an academic exercise, you probably want to use Python's [built-in CSV parser class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to read and parse csv file, Python's csv module might serve better:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open('myfile.csv', 'r'))
for row in reader:
    print(', '.join(row))
```

Although you cannot change the line terminator for reader here, it ends a row with either '\r' or '\n', which works for your case.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator

Again, for most of the cases, I don't think you need to parse csv file manually. There are a few issues/reasons that makes csv module easier for you: field containing separator, field containing newline character, field containing quote character, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`string.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), which (with no arguments) removes any whitespace from the start and end of a string:

```
for r in rows:
    print(r.strip())
```

If you want to remove only newlines, you can pass that character as an argument to `strip`:

```
for r in rows:
    print(r.strip('\n'))
```

---

For a clean solution, you could use a generator to wrap `open`, like this:

```
def open_no_newlines(*args, **kwargs):
    with open(*args, **kwargs) as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line.strip('\n')
```

You can then use `open_no_newlines` like this:

```
for line in open_no_newlines('myfile.csv', mode='r'):
    print(line)
```

Comment: I mean there is some way to do that setting some `open` parameters?

Comment: You can replace newlines with `\r`, or `\r\n` using open parameters, but you cannot remove them.  Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: @chrisz which are the parameter you're talking about?

Comment: `open()` has a parameter called `newlines`.  I linked the documentation earlier.